# ElasticSearch - JSON processor outputs a single field name, leaving out the rest

Tags: json, elasticsearch, pipeline

I am using an **ingest pipeline** to inject some logs to ElasticSearch, which I've parsed using [Grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/grok-processor.html).
I have managed to extract pretty much all the data I need, including a string (`json_data`) that I need to convert to a JSON object using ES's [JSON processor.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html)

This is the kind of logs I'm dealing with:

```
[2020-09-08T15:00:48.231213+02:00] security.INFO: Description {"ip_address":"123.45.0.1","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0","mobile":false,"base_reference":"demo_referentiel","base":"demo","user_id":"5","login":"admin_abc","type":"security"} []
```

And below is the Processors configuration for my pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}]%{SPACE}%{WORD:logger}.%{WORD:log_level}:%{SPACE}%{DATA:description}%{SPACE}{%{GREEDYDATA:json_data}}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:additional_data}"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "json": {
      "field": "json_data",
      "target_field": "json_data_parsed"
    }
  }
]
```

In the end, the `"json_data"` field looks like this:

```
"ip_adress":"123.45.0.1","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0","mobile":false,"base_reference":"demo_referentiel","base":"demo","user_id":"5","login":"admin_abc","type":"security"
```

And, this is where things go wrong; the `"json_data_parsed"` field only contains the first field name. In this example, it is just `ip_address` with nothing else.
*Edit: `Definition` is a placeholder, it will most often contain several words, separated by spaces*

How comes the processor doesn't seem to read the JSON right and what can I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution:

In this case and with the format I was given, I needed to create a custom pattern specially for the JSON object.

I did it using the `pattern_definitions` [(doc)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/grok-processor.html#custom-patterns) attribute of Grok, which allowed me to keep the brackets from being excluded from the string.

Here is the definition for the `JSON` pattern, which is basically a `GREEDYDATA` pattern with added brackets:

```
  "pattern_definitions": {
    "JSON": "{.*}"
   }
```

Now, my full Grok pattern looks like this (also simplified thanks to [@Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val)):

```
"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}] %{WORD:logger}.%{WORD:log_level}: %{GREEDYDATA:description} %{JSON:json_data} %{GREEDYDATA:additional_data}"
```

Hoping this'll help a few others.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured something out.

Answer (score 1):

Great start!! I suggest two changes to make it work

1. One is to remove all `%{SPACE}` occurrences and simply have normal verbatim spaces
2. The other is two remove the surrounding curly braces around `%{GREEDYDATA:json_data}`

It would look like this:

```
"processors": [
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}]%{SPACE}%{WORD:logger}.%{WORD:log_level}: %{DATA:description} %{GREEDYDATA:json_data} %{GREEDYDATA:additional_data}"
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

You'd end up with something like this:

```
    "_source" : {
      "additional_data" : "[]",
      "logger" : "security",
      "log_level" : "INFO",
      "description" : "Description",
      "message" : """[2020-09-08T15:00:48.231213+02:00] security.INFO: Description {"ip_address":"123.45.0.1","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0","mobile":false,"base_reference":"demo_referentiel","base":"demo","user_id":"5","login":"admin_abc","type":"security"} []""",
      "json_data_parsed" : {
        "user_id" : "5",
        "mobile" : false,
        "ip_address" : "123.45.0.1",
        "login" : "admin_abc",
        "type" : "security",
        "base_reference" : "demo_referentiel",
        "http_user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0",
        "base" : "demo"
      },
      "json_data" : """{"ip_address":"123.45.0.1","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0","mobile":false,"base_reference":"demo_referentiel","base":"demo","user_id":"5","login":"admin_abc","type":"security"}""",
      "timestamp" : "2020-09-08T15:00:48.231213+02:00"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did suspect the lack of brackets to be the issue. I've modified my grok pattern as suggested. It needs a bit more tuning as `json_data` now contains part of my "Description" message (which can be basically anything, even a quite long sentence). I'll keep you updated.

Comment: The _source document I posted above is exactly the one that comes out of the pipeline using the grok processor with the modified pattern I suggested, but I think `Description` is actually a multi token sentence, right? In that case `DATA` is not the right pattern to use

Comment: Exactly, I edited it out for privacy's sake but it could also be a full-on sentence, like "connection attempt failed" or something of the sort.

Comment: It's a difficult one for grok, because there are also spaces in the JSON. If you can enclose the description without double quotes it'd be easier

Comment: If the brackets are part of the issue, wouldn't it be possible to add them with a Set processor? I'm also currently trying to see if a custom pattern definition (`{.*}`) for JSON couldn't do the trick.

Comment: Also, maybe I did not understand you completely, but the `Description` part already doesn't have quotes. Should it?

Comment: Adding quotes would help single out the description part out of the rest and facilitate the parsing with a `QUOTEDSTRING` pattern

Comment: I have managed to make it work with the custom pattern definition. I can now fetch the right data with the right format, but for some reason now it's the JSON processor that's acting out.
Anyways, that is not directly related to the question so thanks for your help on this one !

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!